# Cannot read the output video after using CV2 Video Writer

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I didn't managed to open the .avi file after i have performed videowrite.cv2.

Is there any way to solve the issues?

Able to write but not able to read as it said corrupted data.

Below is the sample code
:

```
day_video = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/gdrive/Shareddrives/Computer Vision/Assignment 2/Q1_day_video.avi')
check, frame = day_video.read()
height, width, _ = frame.shape
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (height, width))
while day_video.isOpened():
  check, frame = day_video.read()
  if not check:
    out.release()
    break
  new_output = lines_highlighted_day(frame)
  out.write(new_output)

out.release()
```

[image: can't play]

Comment: The size parameter of `VideoWriter` constructor should have width first, and height second. Since you swapped the values, you're writing invalid frames, which are ignored, The means your output video file contains no frames, which makes it unplayable (should be fairly obvious given its small size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height & video in this line

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (height, width))
```

to

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_day.avi', fourcc, 20, (width, height ))
```

Comment: never ever give values the wrong names. your first recommendation just blew my mind.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Got your point. I edited.

Comment: This still isn't a very useful answer. Why should the OP do this? What was the problem? ( Ideally add some references to the actual documentation.)